# REST: Deleting non-canonical resources

Tags: rest

- If `/users/{username}` is an **alias** of `/users/{userId}` (one cannot exist without the other) then I am expecting that deleting the former means that you want to delete the latter.
- If `/lists/{listId}/users/{userId}` is an **reference** to `/users/{userId}` (one can exist without the other) then I'm expecting to be able to delete the reference without affecting the canonical resource.
- In both cases, invoking `HTTP GET` will result in [HTTP 303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) to the canonical resource.

I believe that it is confusing that both types behave the same for `HTTP GET` but not for `HTTP DELETE`.

This has led me to the following questions:

1. What should happen when `HTTP DELETE` is invoked on an *alias*?
2. What is the appropriate way to remove references from a list without removing the actual object they point to?

Comment: I upvoted your question because I too am curious.  However, I see at least 5 questions here.  What is your canonical question (pun intended)?

Comment: @Madbreaks, I see only 3 questions (listed at the end). What are the other two? My canonical question is how to remove items from a list but in answering that question I think we must also answer how to treat `DELETE` non-canonical URIs.

Comment: Just count your question marks. I guess I was considering those questions.  Regardless, you really need to ask a single question, with 7.5k rep I'm sure you know that though.

Comment: @Madbreaks, I've reduced the number of questions to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[5.3.5.  DELETE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-5.3.5)

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the target
> resource.  This method MAY be overridden by human intervention (or
> other means) on the origin server.  The client cannot be guaranteed
> that the operation has been carried out, even if the status code
> returned from the origin server indicates that the action has been
> completed successfully.  However, the server SHOULD NOT indicate
> success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends to
> delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible location.

**> A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes a

> representation describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action has
> not yet been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been
> enacted but the response does not include a representation.**

So:

> If /users/{username} is an alias of /users/{userId} (one cannot exist without the other)
> then > I am expecting that deleting the former means that you want to delete the latter
>
> **What should happen when HTTP DELETE is invoked on an alias?**

"both" resources must to be deleted. as i understand if one can not exist without other they are just different identifiers of same resource, so after deleting one of them following requests must be answered with 404 Not Found for both.

> What is the appropriate way to remove references from a list without removing the actual object they point to?

**UPDATE:**

> My question is what HTTP methods should be used to indicate that a client would like to remove references from a list?

If user(client?) would like to remove reference from a list without removing actual resource there is only one way - client must send PUT request with modified list to the server which means that existing list must be replaced with a new one. If user doesn't have enough permissions "403 Forbidden" can be returned in response.

To do the reverse of this(i.e. inform user when list was changed) if resource(i.e. list in this case) is supposed to be cached on client side and removal of some other resource affects this list, only approach i can think to "inform" user is to use caches. For example:

**REQUEST**

```
GET /list HTTP/1.1
Host: service.org
```

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/...
Content-Length: ...
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
ETag: a32lasdf
```

In the response above Cache-Control header value "private, max-age=0" is an instruction for client that it can cache representation locally though must send following request to the server each time:

**REQUEST**

```
GET /list HTTP/1.1
Host: service.org
If-None-Match: a32lasdf
```

if /list resource is untouched then ETag value will match "If-None-Match" value, server can respond with "304 Not Modified" and client doesn't need to do anything. But if previous removal action affected the /list, hash code for ETag will be different from one which is provided with "If-None-Match" header and thus new representation of the /list resource will be returned by server.

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-7.4.4 `This status code is generally applicable to any HTTP method`. This conflicts with what the specification says about `DELETE`. I can't delete an alias without deleting the canonical resource. `/users/{username}` is a search query that returns `/users/{userId}`. I can't hide search results.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my second question. How should a client indicate to the server that they would like to remove references from a list? I understand how to implement this under the hood, but the REST design is unclear.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly. A user can have permission to edit a sub-section of a list. I allow `HTTP PUT` but take note of which portions he modified and issue `403 Forbidden` or `200 Ok` accordingly. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

URIs are references to resources, not the resources themselves. In a sense, they are all canonical. Different URIs may identify the same resource. They may also be pleceholders for something that doesn't even exist yet. The "one cannot exist without the other" concept is something specific to the application, it's not a REST constraint. Ideally, you won't have URIs depending on each other. If you delete the resource all URIs pointing to it will point to nothing. Or at least that's how things should be if the URIs were pointing to resources and not to one another.

**UPDATE:**

According to [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> 1.1 Overview of URI:
>
> ...
>
> Resource
>
> A resource can be anything that has identity.  Familiar
>   examples include an electronic document, an image, a service
>   (e.g., "today's weather report for Los Angeles"), and a
>   collection of other resources.  Not all resources are network
>   "retrievable"; e.g., human beings, corporations, and bound
>   books in a library can also be considered resources.
>
> **The resource is the conceptual mapping to an entity or set of
>   entities**, not necessarily the entity which corresponds to that
>   mapping at any particular instance in time.  Thus, a resource
>   can remain constant even when its content---the entities to
>   which it currently corresponds---changes over time, provided
>   that the conceptual mapping is not changed in the process.
>
> Identifier
>
> **An identifier is an object that can act as a reference to
>   something that has identity.**  In the case of URI, the object is
>   a sequence of characters with a restricted syntax.

**UPDATE:**

I guess, if the resource is accessible/modifiable through multiple URIs, it's up to the application to designate a canonical one (the URI that is going to be included in the hypertext of responses). But yes, it's the URIs that are non-canonical (from the application's point of view), not the resources.

Comment: `URIs are references to resource representations, not the resources themselves`. Wikipedia disagrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Comment: The key point I was trying to get across is that URIs are references to **resources** not resource **representations**. A **representation** in the context of REST is the request/response entity body. I assume this isn't what you had in mind?

Comment: `they are all canonical`. No. Multiple canonical URIs cannot point to the same resource. Multiple non-canonical URIs can. `one cannot exist without the other [...] is something specific to the application`: Good point. So you're saying both are just non-canonical URIs except that one can be removed and the other can't (due to application-specific constraints).

Comment: I concur, URIs are references to resources, not to resource representations. I'll fix the post to reflect that.